# Writing a jasmine test to inspect a mock input control

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a parent component that has a child component called 'line'.  I have to write a jasmine test in the parent component that will investigate the values in Input controls in the line component.

I'm having a hard time setting up a mock Input control.

The code I need to test is like this:
  result = line.lineForm.controls['valueControl'].value

So I'm trying to set up a test that will allow me to create a mock control (assuming that's what I need) and to reference it in the code.

The test code below shows some of what I've been trying, but I keep getting an error because I'm trying to retrieve the value of an undefined object.

```
valueControl = jasmine.createSpyObj('Input', ['formControlName','value','id']);
valueControl.value = 5;
valueControl.formControlName = 'valueControl';
valueControl.id = 'valueControl';

const controlList = jasmine.createSpyObj('QueryList<Input>', ['filter', 'length', 'forEach', 
      'pop', 'toArray']);
 const lines = jasmine.createSpyObj('QueryList<LineComponent>', ['filter','length', 
   'forEach','pop','toArray']);
 const line = jasmine.createSpyObj('LineComponent', ['enableForm','lineForm',]);
 const lineFormGroup = jasmine.createSpyObj('FormGroup', ['enable', 'controls', 'valueControl', 
    'valueControl2']);
 controlList.length = 1;
 controlList.pop.and.returnValue(valueControl);

 lineFormGroup.controls = controlList;
 lineFormGroup.valueControl = valueControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled if you use a StubComponent instead of actual dependent component. Refer to this link below on how we populate @ViewChild. This has detailed description on how to test the dependent components and how to mock the dependencies. 
https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-unit-testing-viewchild-4525e0c7b756

If you are using @ViewChildren and have injected the dependent components, then your child component will work well if you stub out the dependent component. You can use a LineStubComponent and add providers in your component declaration. You can make adjustments to your stub component based on what use case you are testing.
providers: [
    {
      provide: LineComponent,
      useClass: LineStubComponent
    }
  ]

I hope that helps.